# Yii table relations

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

I am really new to Yii. I have 3 tables:

1. Suppliers(sid, sname) //pk -> sid,
2. Products(pid, pname) //pk -> pid,
3. IncomingProducts(pid, sid, qty) //pk -> (pid, sid)

I want to form a relation in table `IncomingProducts` such that I can retrieve the following information at once: (pname, sname, qty).

All this information should be based on the table `IncomingProducts`.
Any help?

Comment: you need to name primary key column `id`..you can't have sid, or pid..as pk.

Comment: @RajatSinghal yes you can use composite primary keys. Although that would limit the number of product/supplier combinations in the IncomingProducts table, as you couldn't have more than one record for each product/supplier combination

Answer (score 1):

IncomingProducts must contain id->pk field, because it can contain many record with the same (pid, sid) pair.

And any record (id, pid, sid, qty) has one Suplier and one Product, so relations of IncomingProducts model is:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'supplier' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Suppliers', array('sid'=>'sid')),
        'product' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Products', array('pid'=>'pid')),
    );
}
```

Not sure about FK - `array('sid'=>'sid')`, but think `'sid'` shouldn't work (you need to specify key of 'IncomingProducts' which contains 'Supliers.sid'). About using 'fk'=>'pk' relations you can read here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#relations-detail

You can get all incoming products for any suplier with relation in Supliers model:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'incoming' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'IncomingProducts', 'sid'),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming a many-to-many relation between suppliers and products. In IncomingProducts, you can define the relations as follows,

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'suppliers' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Suppliers', 'sid'),
        'products' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Products', 'pid'),
    );
}
```

You can read more about Yii's relational active record [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr)